# Cauchy Sequences, not converging to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

True or False? If $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy and $x_n + y_n > 0$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\left\{\frac{1}{(x_n + y_n)}\right\}$ cannot converge to zero.

I believe the claim to be False: If both sequences are Cauchy, then they are convergent and therefore bounded. Then there exists a positive number for which the sequences is less than or equal to that positive number. Then $1/(x_n + y_n) \leq M$ for all $n$. However, by Cauchy Theorem, a sequence must approach a real value. Then in this case it would be zero, but $x_n + y_n > 0$,therefore it cannot approach zero.

Does this make sense? Can someone please help me, clarify? Any feedback would be really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: To disprove a general statement, you should come up with a counterexample.  All you would need in this case is to find one satisfactory set of Cauchy sequences where the statement does not apply.  However, as the answer points out, that's impossible.

Comment: In fact, your statements all seem to be proving the statement true, so your answer would have been correct if you simply wrote "true" rather than "false" and kept the same explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true. If the sequences $\{x_n\}$  and $\{y_n\}$ are Cauchy, then they are both bounded. Thus there is an $M\gt 0$ such that $|x_n|\lt M$ for all $n$, and $|y_n|\lt M$ for all $n$. It follows that $|x_n+y_n|\lt 2M$ for all $n$. Thus the sequence
  $\{\frac{1}{x_n+y_n}\}$ cannot have limit $0$.

**Remark:** We did not need the condition $x_n+y_n\gt 0$. We have left a few little gaps in the argument, which for a fully detailed proof should be filled. We assumed that you already had seen a proof of the fact that Cauchy sequences are bounded. The fact that if $|x_n+y_n|\lt 2M$, then the reciprocal sequence cannot have limit $0$ can, if you wish, be proved by a straightforward $\epsilon$-$N$ argument.